# How to post request to API using only code?

Tags: python, api, python-requests, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am developing a DAG to be scheduled on Apache Airflow which main porpuse will be to post survey data (on json format) to an API and then getting a response (the answers to the surveys). Since this whole process is going to be automated, every part of it has to be programmed in the DAG, so I can´t use Postman or any similar app (unless there is a way to automate their usage, but I don't know if this is possible).
I was thinking of using the *requests* library for Python, and the function I've written for posting the json to the API looks like this:

```
def postFileToAPI(**context):
    print('uploadFileToAPI() ------ ')
    json_file = context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='toJson') ## this pulls the json file from a previous task
    print('--------------- Posting survey request to API')
    r = requests.post('https://[request]', data = json_file)
```

(I haven't finished defining the http link for the request because my source data is incomplete.)

However, since this is my frst time working with APIs and the *requests* library, I don't know if this is enough. For example, I'm unsure if I need to provide a token from the API to perform the request.
I also don't know if there are other libraries that are better suited for this or that could be a good support.
In short: I don't know if what I'm doing will work as intended, what other information I need t provide my DAG or if there are any libraries to make my work easier.

Comment: Also, should I execute the post and get commands in the same task or can they be done separetly?

Answer (score 0):

The Python requests package that you're using is all you need, except if you're making a request that needs extra authorisation - then you should also import for example requests_jwt (then `from requests_jwt import JWTAuth`) if you're using JSON web tokens, or whatever relevant requests package corresponds for your authorisation style.

You make POST and GET requests and all individual requests separately.

Include the URL and data arguments as you have done and that should work!

You may also need `headers` and/or `auth` arguments to get through security,
eg for the GitLab api for a private repository you would include these extra arguments, where GITLAB_TOKEN is a GitLab web token.

````
```headers={'PRIVATE-TOKEN': GITLAB_TOKEN},
auth=JWTAuth(GITLAB_TOKEN)```
````

If you just try it it should work, if it doesn't work then test the API with curl requests directly in the Terminal, or let us know :)